# SendGrid SMTP API: Multiple e-mails to the same recipient

Tags: email, sendgrid

I have a web app that uses SendGrid's X-SMTP functionality to construct a single e-mail that is then merged and forwarded to a list of recipients specified in the X-SMTPAPI header.

Documentation here: http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/

I am using MVC.NET and sending the e-mail using a MailMessage object via smtp.sendgrid.net

Everything seems to be working fine as far as merging values from the header and sending out the e-mails is concerned.

However I have noticed that if I specify the same e-mail address multiple times in the "to" list, only a single e-mail is sent out (or at least I just receive the one).

Has anybody had the same experience? Anybody know of a way to get around this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SendGrid's servers will de-dupe the `To` array. The only way to get around this is to split duplicates into separate SMTP messages, or to change the addresses so they are not duplicates (you could use plus addressing, e.g. `person@example.com` and `person+foo@example.com`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Is this documented anywhere? Is there really no way to disable this behavior?

Comment: If you specify unique data for the 2 recipients, e.g. different unique_args or substitution values, then 2 messages will be sent. Keep in mind the messages will have the same SMTP ID, so some clients (like gmail) will only show one of the messages.

Comment: To answer your other questions: we will update the documentation (thanks!), and there is no way to disable the behavior. Can you explain your use case a little bit? We don't often have people that intentionally want to send duplicates.

Comment: Thanks again, I'll look into mixing some unique_args in there. My scenario is a competition where users can participate in multiple groups. Rather than combining the results for all the user's groups into one big complicated result e-mail we have decided to go for separate e-mails outlining the results for each group.

Comment: So, I tried adding an array of unique_args with the name uid and a value of randomly generated guid, and the SendGrid control panel does indeed show all e-mails as being sent, including the duplicate addresses. As you mention, though, my client (or maybe Exchange server?) only shows a single e-mail received.

Comment: Yeah that is what I feared would happen :( The best advice I can give in this situation is to split the duplicates out of your array into different SMTP messages. If you have more than 2 occurrences in your array it might make sense to use  a recursive function to do this.

Comment: @bwest: I'm having this problem too. My use case is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28051007/sendgrid-recepients-with-the-same-email. Maybe you can give me some guidance...