# Sendgrid recepients with the same email

Tags: sendgrid

In a NodeJs app I want to use SendGrid to send email reminders to people signed up to different kind of events. At a regular interval the app collect ready reminders and send these. The number or reminders can vary from zero to many at every check.

If for example 3 reminder-to-be-sent are found at a certain check, and two of these have the same recipient (same email), because it acutally is the same persone who has signed up on two different events. In this case I would actually need to send out two email (with different content/substitution) to the same email/recepient

Is several SMTP calls the best solution here?

This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21610981/sendgrid-smtp-api-multiple-e-mails-to-the-same-recipient).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SendGrid will de-duplicate multiple instances of the same address within a single SMTP message. If you need to send multiple customized messages to the same address, you'll need to make sure they're unique SMTP messages, not just unique entries in the SMTPAPI header.

Answer (score 1):

As the answer to the related question suggests, SendGrid will remove duplicate email addresses from the 'To' field, so you would need to send the two reminders separately. However, from a user experience perspective, you may want to collate the reminders on the server side and combine them into one email for the user, altering the subject line to include the number of reminders that are in the email:

'Hey *user*, you have 2 new reminders!'

Comment: I have multiple substitutions that need to be in one email - for example, if a user has multiple 'nicknames' - those should all appear in the body of one email. I'm using a SendGrid template. I'm passing an array of 'nicknames' to an AddSubstitutions method with a '-nickname-' key to the SMTP header. However, only the first substitution for nickname appears in the email. Any ideas are appreciated!